# I want to change the output value of the string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char str[101];
    int i;
    int j=1;
    scanf("%s", str);
    for(i=0; str[i]!='\0'; i++) {
        if(i!=0 && i%j==0) {
            printf("\n");
            j++;
        }
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
}
```

If I input "abcdefg" in this code, I want it printed in turn like stairs.
a(\n)
bc(\n)
def(\n)
g
How fix code?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char str[101];
    int i;
    int j=1,k=0;
    scanf("%s", str);

    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i=k+i)
    {
         for(j=i;j<=i+k && str[j]!='\0';j++)
             printf("%c", str[j]);
         k++;
         if(str[j]!='\0')
             printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could fix your problem

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int i,j=1,k;
   char str[100];
   scanf("%s",str);
   for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
   {
     for(k=0;k<j;k++)
     {
       if(str[k+i]!='\0')
         printf("%c",str[k+i]);
       else
         exit(1);
     }
     printf("\n");
     j++;
     i=k+i-1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```